# Reshape panda dataframe in a specific way Part 2

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape

I have an another specific task for reshaping a panda dataframe.

I have the same python code

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': [123, 123,124], 'Method': ['angular', 'angular','angular'], 'Colour': ['red', 'blue','Noir'], 'Size': [20, 30,10] }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['ID','Method','Colour','Size'])
df

ID  Method  Colour  Size
123 angular red     20
123 angular blue    30
124 angular Noir    10
```

With the following code

```
resul = df.reset_index().set_index(['ID', 'Method', 'index']
                                   ).unstack().reset_index() #.groupby(['ID','Method'])

resul.columns = [i if j == '' else i + '_' + str(j)
                 for i, j in resul.columns.tolist()]
resul
```

I get the following result

```
    ID  Method  Colour_0    Colour_1    Colour_2    Size_0  Size_1  Size_2
0   123 angular   red         blue        NaN         20.0    30.0   NaN
1   124 angular   NaN         NaN         Noir        NaN     NaN    10.0
```

But what want is that the code count how many colours each ID has and then keep the maximum (related to df, the ID=123 has two colours and ID=124 has one coulour). That is, it will keep the number two and should create only two news colours (coulour_0 and colour_1) instead of 3. The same also for the column **Size**. It should have only two columns. The result table should looks like

```
    ID  Method  Colour_0    Colour_1    Size_0  Size_1  
0   123 angular   red         blue        20.0    30.0  
1   124 angular   Noir        NaN          10.0    NaN
```

It doesn't matter in which order the NaN comes up for both.

Can someone please help me? Thanks in advance

Comment: It is advised that you [upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400) solutions that help and [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) one of them.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way using [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html). Note that we need to create the columns of the pivoted dataframe, to have them numbered we can go with `GroupBy.cumcount`:

```
g = df.groupby('ID').Colour.cumcount()
out = df.pivot_table(index=['ID', 'Method'], 
                     columns=g,
                     values=['Colour', 'Size'],
                     aggfunc='first')

# combine both levels in the MultiIndex column into one
out.columns = ['_'.join(map(str, t)) for t in out.columns]
print(out.reset_index())

   ID   Method  Colour_0 Colour_1  Size_0  Size_1
0  123  angular      red     blue    20.0    30.0
1  124  angular     Noir      NaN    10.0     NaN
```

Comment: Hi yatu, thanks a lot. It works perfectly as expected

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
resul = df.set_index(['ID', 'Method', df.groupby('ID')['Colour'].cumcount()]).unstack()
resul.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' for i, j in resul.columns]
resul = resul.reset_index()
print(resul)
```

Output:

```
    ID   Method Colour_0 Colour_1  Size_0  Size_1
0  123  angular      red     blue    20.0    30.0
1  124  angular     Noir      NaN    10.0     NaN
```